# What is wrong with my logic? Trying to make a simple mysqli script

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to make a PHP script to my FluxBB forum which uses activation key provided by user to upgrade them and give them an active subscription. When I click "activate" button, nothing happens. I guess something is wrong with my logic, what could it be?

I've tried multiple things such as changing logic and making code simpler, debugging. But I'm stuck with this problem.

```
if(isset($_POST['activate']))
{
    // $pun_user['id'] is User ID
    // csgo is subscription ending time
    $motify_checksub = "SELECT `csgo` FROM `".$db->prefix."users` WHERE `id` = ".$pun_user['id'] or error('[Motify] Unable to check subscription', __FILE__, __LINE__, $db->error());
    $db->query($motify_checksub);
    $motify_sub_result = $db->fetch_assoc($motify_checksub);


    $motify_now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    // has active subscription already?
    if ($motify_sub_result > $motify_now)
    {
        $motify_akey = $db->escape($_POST['key']);
        // check if activation key is valid and not used
        $motify_check_key = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `".$db->prefix."keys` WHERE `akey` = '".$motify_akey."' AND `used` = '0'") or error('[Motify] Unable to validate activation key', __FILE__, __LINE__, $db->error());
        $motify_key_result = $db->num_rows($motify_keycheck);
        if ($motify_key_result > 0)
        {
            // check key value (30 days, 90 days or 365 days)
            $motify_checklength = "SELECT `sub` FROM `".$db->prefix."keys` WHERE `akey` = '".$motify_akey or error('[Motify] Unable to subscription length', __FILE__, __LINE__, $db->error());
            $db->query($motify_checklength);
            $motify_length = $db->fetch_assoc($motify_checklength);
            if ($motify_length == 30) // seems like this key gives 30 days subscription
            {
                // let's check when does this user's current subscription end
                $motify_checkcsgo = "SELECT `csgo` FROM `".$db->prefix."users` WHERE `id` = '".$pun_user['id'] or error('[Motify] Unable to check current subscription time', __FILE__, __LINE__, $db->error());
                $db->query($motify_checkcsgo);
                $motify_csgo = $db->fetch_assoc($motify_checkcsgo);

                // this key is used since now
                $db->query("UDPATE `".$db->prefix."keys` SET `used` = '1' WHERE `akey` = '".$motify_akey) or error('[Motify] Unable to deactivate key', __FILE__, __LINE__, $db->error());

                // let's add those days to his current subscription
                $new30 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $motify_csgo + (24*3600*30));
                $db->query("UPDATE `".$db->prefix."users` SET `csgo` = '".$new30) or error('[Motify] Unable to update subscription', __FILE__, __LINE__, $db->error());
                $db->query("UDPATE `".$db->prefix."users` SET `group_id` = '5' WHERE `id` = '".$pun_user['id']) or error('[Motify] Unable to update group', __FILE__, __LINE__, $db->error());
                redirect("https://example.com/forums/", "Your subscription has been successfully activated! Redirecting...");
            }

            if ($motify_length == 90) // seems like this key gives 90 days subscription
            {
                // let's check when does this user's current subscription end
                $motify_checkcsgo = "SELECT `csgo` FROM `".$db->prefix."users` WHERE `id` = '".$pun_user['id'] or error('[Motify] Unable to check current subscription time', __FILE__, __LINE__, $db->error());
                $db->query($motify_checkcsgo);
                $motify_csgo = $db->fetch_assoc($motify_checkcsgo);

                // this key is used since now
                $db->query("UDPATE `".$db->prefix."keys` SET `used` = '1' WHERE `akey` = '".$motify_akey) or error('[Motify] Unable to deactivate key', __FILE__, __LINE__, $db->error());

                // let's add those days to his current subscription
                $new90 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $motify_csgo + (24*3600*90));
                $db->query("UPDATE `".$db->prefix."users` SET `csgo` = '".$new90) or error('[Motify] Unable to update subscription', __FILE__, __LINE__, $db->error());
                $db->query("UDPATE `".$db->prefix."users` SET `group_id` = '5' WHERE `id` = '".$pun_user['id']) or error('[Motify] Unable to update group', __FILE__, __LINE__, $db->error());
                redirect("https://example.com/forums/", "Your subscription has been successfully activated! Redirecting...");
            }

            if ($motify_length == 365) // seems like this key gives 1 year subscription
            {
                // let's check when does this user's current subscription end
                $motify_checkcsgo = "SELECT `csgo` FROM `".$db->prefix."users` WHERE `id` = '".$pun_user['id'] or error('[Motify] Unable to check current subscription time', __FILE__, __LINE__, $db->error());
                $db->query($motify_checkcsgo);
                $motify_csgo = $db->fetch_assoc($motify_checkcsgo);

                // this key is used since now
                $db->query("UDPATE `".$db->prefix."keys` SET `used` = '1' WHERE `akey` = '".$motify_akey) or error('[Motify] Unable to deactivate key', __FILE__, __LINE__, $db->error());

                $new365 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $motify_csgo + (24*3600*365));
                // let's add those days to his current subscription
                $db->query("UPDATE `".$db->prefix."users` SET `csgo` = '".$new365) or error('[Motify] Unable to update subscription', __FILE__, __LINE__, $db->error());
                // upgrading user to premium group
                $db->query("UDPATE `".$db->prefix."users` SET `group_id` = '5' WHERE `id` = '".$pun_user['id']) or error('[Motify] Unable to update group', __FILE__, __LINE__, $db->error());
                redirect("https://example.com/forums/", "Your subscription has been successfully activated! Redirecting...");
            }
        }
    }

    // expired or no subscription at all
    else
    {
        // this has same logic as above one but this user doesn't have active subscription already or it has been expired

        $motify_akey = $db->escape($_POST['key']);
        $motify_check_key = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `".$db->prefix."keys` WHERE `akey` = '".$motify_akey."' AND `used` = '0'") or error('[Motify] Unable to validate activation key', __FILE__, __LINE__, $db->error());
        $db->query($motify_key_check);
        $motify_key_result = $db->num_rows($motify_keycheck);
        if ($motify_key_result > 0)
        {
            $motify_checklength = "SELECT `sub` FROM `".$db->prefix."keys` WHERE `akey` = '".$motify_akey or error('[Motify] Unable to subscription length', __FILE__, __LINE__, $db->error());
            $db->query($motify_checklength);
            $motify_length = $db->fetch_assoc($motify_checklength);
            if ($motify_length == 30)
            {
                $db->query("UDPATE `".$db->prefix."keys` SET `used` = '1' WHERE `akey` = '".$motify_akey) or error('[Motify] Unable to deactivate key', __FILE__, __LINE__, $db->error());
                $new30 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $motify_csgo (24*3600*30));
                $db->query("UPDATE `".$db->prefix."users` SET `csgo` = '".$new30) or error('[Motify] Unable to update subscription', __FILE__, __LINE__, $db->error());
                $db->query("UDPATE `".$db->prefix."users` SET `group_id` = '5' WHERE `id` = '".$pun_user['id']) or error('[Motify] Unable to update group', __FILE__, __LINE__, $db->error());
                redirect("https://example.com/forums/", "Your subscription has been successfully activated! Redirecting...");
            }
            if ($motify_length == 90)
            {
                $db->query("UDPATE `".$db->prefix."keys` SET `used` = '1' WHERE `akey` = '".$motify_akey) or error('[Motify] Unable to deactivate key', __FILE__, __LINE__, $db->error());
                $new90 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $motify_csgo (24*3600*90));
                $db->query("UPDATE `".$db->prefix."users` SET `csgo` = '".$new90) or error('[Motify] Unable to update subscription', __FILE__, __LINE__, $db->error());
                $db->query("UDPATE `".$db->prefix."users` SET `group_id` = '5' WHERE `id` = '".$pun_user['id']) or error('[Motify] Unable to update group', __FILE__, __LINE__, $db->error());
                redirect("https://example.com/forums/", "Your subscription has been successfully activated! Redirecting...");
            }
            if ($motify_length == 365)
            {
                $db->query("UDPATE `".$db->prefix."keys` SET `used` = '1' WHERE `akey` = '".$motify_akey) or error('[Motify] Unable to deactivate key', __FILE__, __LINE__, $db->error());
                $new365 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $motify_csgo (24*3600*365));
                $db->query("UPDATE `".$db->prefix."users` SET `csgo` = '".$new365) or error('[Motify] Unable to update subscription', __FILE__, __LINE__, $db->error());
                $db->query("UDPATE `".$db->prefix."users` SET `group_id` = '5' WHERE `id` = '".$pun_user['id']) or error('[Motify] Unable to update group', __FILE__, __LINE__, $db->error());
                redirect("https://example.com/forums/", "Your subscription has been successfully activated! Redirecting...");
            }
        }
    }
}





<!-- HTML part -->
    <form method="POST">
            <div class="inform">
                <input type="hidden" name="form_sent" value="1">
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="infldset">
                        <input type="text" maxlength="35" name="key" placeholder="Activation key" required>
                        <input type="submit" name="activate" value="Activate">
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>

        </form>
```

Screenshot of `keys` table:

[image: Screenshot of <code>keys</code> table]

Screenshot of `csgo` column and its format:

[image: Screenshot of <code>csgo</code> column]

(if the user haven't ever had an active subscription it would be NULL)

EDIT: I haven't got a single syntax error

Comment: `or error` is certainly wrong.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @Dharman It's not. It's FluxBB's own function. It shows error instead 500 page. There is nothing wrong with it. Also could you tell me which part is vulnerable, your comment is useless unless you describe it more.

Comment: There is a lot wrong with it. The biggest issue is that string will never be false.

Comment: @Dharman There is already mysqli_escape_realstring

Comment: It should not be used to prevent SQL injection. This function is pretty useless. You should use prepared statements, which will make your code secure and simpler.

Comment: @Dharman Thanks! Could you provide one example with prepared statements in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this bit of code:

```
// check if activation key is valid and not used
$motify_check_key = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `".$db->prefix."keys` WHERE `akey` = '".$motify_akey."' AND `used` = '0'") or error('[Motify] Unable to validate activation key', __FILE__, __LINE__, $db->error());
$motify_key_result = $db->num_rows($motify_keycheck);
if ($motify_key_result > 0)
```

where does `$motify_keycheck` in your second to last line come from? Shouldn't that be `$motify_check_key`? But then, if it is, `num_rows` will always be 1 because you're returning a count. So instead, you want to retrieve the count variable (so give it a name in the query using 'as') and look at the value of it.

As your next query then goes back to the same table to get a different column, you'd be better off combining the two.

In this bit:

```
$motify_length = $db->fetch_assoc($motify_checklength);
if ($motify_length == 30) // seems like this key gives 30 days subscription
```

`$motify_length` is an associative array, so it's never going to be equal to 30. You should be checking `$motify_length['sub']` instead. Same problem with these two:

```
$motify_csgo = $db->fetch_assoc($motify_checkcsgo);
...
$new30 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $motify_csgo + (24*3600*30));
```

I can't see how you don't get errors when you're trying to do operations like that on complete arrays. Some simple debugging using `var_dump` and `echo` would help here.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice my typo on that. It still doesn't work.
I'm not familiar with queries containing 'as' so could you link me good tutorial or make an example query here?

Comment: I'd change the first query to be something like `"SELECT sub FROM `".$db->prefix."keys` WHERE `akey` = '".$motify_akey."' AND `used` = '0'"`, and then use `num_rows` on the result to check if anything was once. Inside your `if()` clause, you then don't need to run the second query because you already have `sub` in the results object from the first. I can't link to tutorials I'm afraid, try some experimenting to get the hang of things.

Comment: Alright so I added an echo if key isn't valid or it has been used. It works until it checks what is the key's value (30, 90, 365). I think the problem starts from here `
            // check key value (30 days, 90 days or 365 days)`

Comment: Then when it's working, read up on prepared statements and change to that.

Comment: Did you notice my edit, where I talk about how you get an array back, not a flat variable?

Comment: Why do you have these separate blocks of code for the different subscription lengths? You already get the length back from the activation key table, why not use that in the calculation instead of all that extra code?

Comment: Shouldn't this query: `$db->query("UPDATE `".$db->prefix."users` SET `csgo` = '".$new90)` have a WHERE clause? Do you really want to update every row in the table?